# How to show actual values instead of sum/average on y-axis in a plot using Power BI

Tags: plot, powerbi

I have an excel sheet which I am plotting two values over time. But when I plot it in Power BI it shows the sum of those values in y-axis rather than the actual value. The plot looks like the following.[image]

If you see the y-axis they are in billions. But if you see the actual data below its in hundred thousands range.

[image]

If I use date hierarchy instead this is how it looks like.

[image]

Comment: What is the time granularity of your data rows? Do those rows correspond to specific days or weeks or what?

Comment: Specific days over 4 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is on specific days, you should use dates on your axis rather than weekends. When you have weekends on the axis, it groups all the days within that week together, which is not what you want.

---

**Edit:**

After looking at your file, it has nothing to do with dates after all. It looks like the data is recorded at a weekly level. The reason its adding up like that though is that for each date there are a bunch of different rows that correspond to different geography (your `geo` column has state name abbreviations).

If you add a slicer for `geo` and look at the chart for a single state at a time, then I think you'll get more what you're expecting.

Comment: So you suggest using the Date hierarchy option instead

Comment: I just added an image on how the plot looks if I use Date hierarchy

Comment: That doesn't look right. Can you post a sample of the data tables involved including the date column? Even better would be the PBIX file.

Comment: Does this work   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1biXnnkxFelJyn64UldQik1iB6AFPFgss

Comment: Thanks a lot. That made sense. I didn't realize it was the same date across different Geo and hence the aggregation. Thank you.